# Rule does not work in infopath SharePoint 2013

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2013, infopath

I hava a form for Production Price. There are 3 columns, Quantity, Price and Total Price. `Quantity * Price = Total Price`.

I use the rule **Set a field’s value** in InfoPath. When `Quantity > 0` Set the Total Price value changes to `Quantity * Price`. But this rule does not work in infopath. Nothing happens.

And if I add `Quantity * Price` to default value of Total Price, it works well. Why it does not work via rule ?

Comment: The rule should be on the Quantity and/or Price fields, not the Total Price field; so that when one of those fields changes they will update the Total Price with the updated value.

Comment: @user2051770 ah, thank you !